# Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1).

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have installed dotnet tool.

install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.0.1 and trying to use in the .net core project 2.1. I am getting this error on setting the project file.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="3.0.1" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

but I am getting this error.

Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.0.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Help??

Answer (score 13):

The the info on the usage here: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli

Basically you will need to remove this from the project file:

```
<-- This line needs to be removed -->
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="X.X.X" />
```

and the tools will need to be installed the following way moving forward:

```
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

Comment: One thing to note, this is a global tool install, not related to your project (that threw me for a minute). This also means you'll need to restart Visual Studio to see the UI effects (like right-click on project and Publish Lambda, etc)

Comment: Unfortunately, this still did not work for my particular project as the right-click "Publish Lambda" was still missing for my project.

Comment: Also, if you do migration of net.core version of your lambda from 1.0 to 2.1 you will need to go to Lamda configuration page and change the version there by hands and make the first deploy by hands using the zip generated by dotnet. Also need to care about project type as already noted.

Answer (score 3):

In late 2019, the tool got moved as a global one, instead of being installed locally within the project, it is installed at a machine level.
Go to package manager console in VS, give the command as below:-

```
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

If its an older project being migrated to newer version, in the project file, the `DotNetCliToolReference` line needs to be removed.

Now the project file has an entry which marks the project as a Lambda function as follows, if not present then this needs to be added manually in the main property group.

```
 <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
```

Ref: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli

Comment: I tried adding the Amazon.Lambda.Tools nuget package to my project as instructed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/) but as your answer correctly states, you are supposed to add it as a global tool. AWS should update their documentation accordingly! Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer above will install the tools locally, you may also need to make sure your csproj includes the AWSProject type. See my answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55712772/407188.

Answer (score 0):

in my case by installing Version 3.3.1  AWS SDK work for me
Install-Package AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup -Version 3.3.1 
or look the appropriate version on this link 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/3.3.1