# cannot install amazon.lambda.tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, nuget, nuget-package

I have a created a simple AWS Dotnet core API in visual studio and now I need to install Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.1.1 NuGet package But, whenever I try to install this NuGet package I get this error

The error:
Package 'Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.1.1' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported (Project name)

I am running VS 2017(15.9.3) on Windows 10 and Dotnet core 2.1.500

Any ideas!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420041/package-amazon-lambda-tools-3-0-1-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp2-1-netcore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding
**Amazon.Lambda.Tools** to csproj and then deleting **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** from csproj